# HC-06 Bluetooth RX & TX voltage (3v3 || 5v)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, voltage-level

I acquired a HC-06 Bluetooth module, and understand that the voltage on the pins must be 3v3 and therefore requires the use of a voltage divider to lower the Arduino's 5v to 3v3 [like this.](http://cdn.instructables.com/FFM/2LM8/HHS9W6IV/FFM2LM8HHS9W6IV.LARGE.jpg)

[image: wiring diagram with 3V3 pullups]

But the page where I purchased the product says the following:

> interface level 3.3V, you can directly connect a variety of SCM (51, AVR, PIC, ARM, MSP430, etc.), 5V microcontroller can also be directly  connected, it can not pass without MAX232 MAX232!

Does this mean I can connect without using a voltage divider?

What does "it can not pass without MAX232 MAX232!" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Some chips that run on 3.3v have 5v tolerant inputs. But it doesn't look like the BC417 does (looking at the datasheet).

So just add the voltage divider.

Answer (score 1):

About the MAX232, I have a Dwengo (similar to Arduino) and to use the HC06 I have to disconnect the serial port(=RS232) else I short circuit my HC06.

After some googling, MAX232 is simply the name of that chip which is required to convert your TX/RX from your bluetooth module to something usable by Arduino.

Source: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAX232