# HC-06 Arduino UNO not working

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-06

Trying to get my HC-06 to work. The idea is to control a addressable RBG LED strip in the future. Currently I'm using a Arduino UNO, some wires and a HC-06. I connect the VCC pin to 5V, GND to GND, RXD to TX and TXD to RX. The module has a red light flashing for a second and after that nothing happens. Any idea what I should do next?

Comment: What have you tried to connect to the HC-06 over bluetooth? Is your phone (or whatever you are using) actually connected to the HC-06? How do you know, that it is not working? What do you think should happen? What are you doing with the HC-06 (you didn't include your code)

Comment: I can't see the HC-06 on my phone, so I can't connect to it. I also found out that the RX pin can only accept 3.3V (previously I only used jumper wires and connected HC-06 directly to Arduino, luckily I have 1k and 2k Ohm resistors if they are needed).The RXD pin on HC is connected to TX (1) on Arduino, TXD is connected to RX (0) on Arduino. For the code I used this: https://i.imgur.com/MhUev3R.png

Comment: Probably need to get a breadboard and watch a video if I need to connect the resistors. Maybe if you could help me with a code? Later on I'll have 28 LED's connected to pin ~6 and I'd like to control it via bluetooth on my phone.

Comment: 2 things: 1. Please copy&paste the code as text into your question. 2. Where did you get that code? It uses pin 0 and 1 for software serial, which cannot work, since hardware serial is on these pins. Also I don't see, why the delay should be needed

Comment: Is it required to use resisistors since RX pin needs 3.3V, I'm using USB atm but will use a 5V power bank in the future?

Comment: [This question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/hc-06-bluetooth-rx-tx-voltage-3v3-5v) might be helpful for this. Your specific module might be 5V tolerant, but I think most HC-06 modules aren't. Look at what your seller says and then decide, if you wanna trust him with this. Or just add the voltage divider, since it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Voltage divider didin't work. So I'm connecting HC-06 to Arduino, the module flashes like 10 times and then stops (the light turns off). Isn't it supposed to keep flashing until a device gets connected to it? Currently just want my phone to be able to see this BT module. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Starting to think that the module is not working. Literally following Youtube guides, they are able to see the HC-06 bluetooth right after connecting the wires. Also their module keeps flashing...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mTlJ7fK.png This is what it currently looks like, using 1k and 2k resistors (followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6E5mP70jaw&t=1s). Do I need to give the Arduino a code for the module to start working? Currently is still just flashes and then the light turns off.

Comment: I don't know, how your module is set up. You should first implement the communication between Arduino and HC-06 (and the communication to the PC for forwarding). Then you can test, if the HC-06 is still alive at the point, that it stops flashing. You can communicate with the HC-06 with AT commands like described at [this site](http://www.puntoflotante.net/BOLT-SYSTEM-BLUETOOTH-AT-COMMANDS.htm). But for that, first fix your wiring. In your photo you are using hardware RX and TX pins, whereas the video tutorial uses different pins. Thats essential

Comment: I ordered a new module (also HC-06), this one is working. Guess the old one was sold to me in a broken state...

Comment: But thank you all so much for the help, can continue with the project now.